# How to overcome outliers on time series data?

Tags: time-series, outliers, seasonality

How to overcome outliers on time series data?
Is there any reference mentioning that to analyze seasonal time series data outliers shouldn't exist?

If I use SAS 9.3, the Bartlett statistics showed no seasonal period.
If I use JDEMetra+ (without considering any outlier), it showed that there is a seasonal trend but no period.
Any suggestion for what I should do next?

Answer (score 0):

Outliers can occur in any time series. http://docplayer.net/12080848-Outliers-level-shifts-and-variance-changes-in-time-series.html should be augmented to consider seasonal pulses e.g. if you have 144 monthly observations and there was no seasonal pulse for december for the first 6 years BUT a significant december effect for the last 6 years. Unfortunately SAS doesn't detect the presence of a seasonal pulse that starts after the beginning of the series. If you wish to post your data I might be of more help.

Essentially outliers can be "overcome" i.e. accommodated by identifying them and then incorporating dummy predictor series to provide the adjustment. This exploratory data analysis naturally leads to finding out possible reasons for the "anomaly". The trick is to identify both the ARIMA structure and the outliers SIMULTANEOUSLY rather than assuming no outliers and constructing an ARIMA model to identify what you assumed didn't exist in the first step.